# How to use "ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering" in swift?

Tags: sorting, swift, ios8, addressbook

What to pass as a value for the parameter "sortOrdering" in the following function?

```
let temp = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook: self.objAddressBook, source: sourceOfAddressBook, sortOrdering: .......)
```

I have values for "addressBook" and "source"

What I am passing "kABPersonSortByFirstName", it is giving me following error!

> Cannot convert the expression's type '(addressBook: @lvalue ABAddressBook!, source: @lvalue Unmanaged!, sortOrdering: Int)' to type '$T5'

While it is working in Objective C!

Answer (score 1):

```
let temp = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook: self.objAddressBook!, source: sourceOfAddressBook!, sortOrdering: ABPersonGetSortOrdering())
```

**Displaying Person Records**

> **ABPersonGetSortOrdering**
>
> Returns the user’s sort-ordering preference for lists of persons.
>
> **Declaration SWIFT**
>
> func ABPersonGetSortOrdering() -> ABPersonSortOrdering
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The user’s sort ordering preference

[ABPersonGetSortOrdering](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonGetSortOrdering)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how will I set ABPersonSortOrdering?

Comment: Do you want to override the user's preference?

Comment: It will return sort by first or last name depending on the user's choice

Comment: No I don't but now it is giving me new error!
"Cannot convert the expression's type '(addressBook: @lvalue ABAddressBook!, source: (At The Rate)lvalue Unmanaged<ABRecord>!, sortOrdering: ABPersonSortOrdering)' to type 'Unmanaged<CFArray>!'"

Comment: You don't have to declare this function.

Comment: I am not declaring the function but how can I use this statement to get the sorted array of my contacts!
Can you please rewrite the statement without issue?
Please check the error I have mentioned above!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68062/discussion-between-developer-and-leonardo-savio-dabus).